# Access SQL - Delete records with same identifiers based on criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with multiple records with the same identifier. I want to remove just one of those records.

```
OrderNum    Cost
10001       254
10002       343
10002       300
10003       435
10003       323
```

For the above table, lets say I just want to delete the records with duplicate Order Numbers that have the smaller cost. Ex: Records 10002, keep the one with a cost of 343, delete the smaller 300.

Here is the query I have come up with, however I am using the cost to identify the duplicate which is bad if there is a similar cost somewhere else in the table.

```
DELETE Orders.*
FROM Orders
WHERE (cost In 
(Select min(cost) FROM Orders 
           GROUP BY [OrderNum] HAVING Count(*) > 1))
```

How can I query through using the Order Number and deleting the one smaller of value that has a duplicate?

Comment: Does the table not have a ***primary key**?*  This is one of the many reasons to have a ***unique identifier*** in every table.

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain the solution in stages:

```
SELECT OrderNum, Min(Cost) as MinCost
FROM Orders
GROUP BY OrderNum
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This returns records you intend to delete:

```
OrderNum MinCost
10002 300
10003 323
```

The following is another version of the same query using sub-`SELECT`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT OrderNum, Min(Cost) as MinCost
FROM Orders
GROUP BY OrderNum
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) M
```

We want to join the marked for deletion records back to the `Orders` table, one way to achieve this is using an EXISTS statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders O
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT OrderNum, Min(Cost) as MinCost
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY OrderNum
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) M
    WHERE O.OrderNum = M.OrderNum
    AND O.Cost = M.MinCost
)
```

Now that we've mastered the `SELECT` statement needed, we turn it into the DELETE statement:

```
DELETE
FROM Orders O
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT OrderNum, Min(Cost) as MinCost
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY OrderNum
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) M
    WHERE O.OrderNum = M.OrderNum
    AND O.Cost = M.MinCost
)
```

If you have large amounts of data, you may wish to create an index to optimize join:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Orders_001 ON Orders (OrderNum, Cost);
```

Comment: This works great! My only issue is that it freezes up with large Tables. I'm working with a table with over 210k records, 10k being ones with duplicates. But I decided to test this solution on a dummy table such as the one in my OP and it worked as intended.

Comment: Hi @SolidSnake, I've updated the answer to reflect an index you'll need. The actual `DELETE` is unchanged, but having the right index changes the execution plan and achieves your results faster.

Answer (score 0):

You want to really do something like:

```
WHERE (ordernum, cost) IN (SELECT ordernum, min(cost) as cost FROM Orders GROUP BY OrderNum HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

But Access doesn't support tuples like this as many larger RDBMS's do.

Instead you could concatenate your tuples:

```
WHERE ordernum & cost IN (SELECT ordernum & min(cost) FROM Orders GROUP BY OrderNum HAVING Count(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all duplicates but the largest one for each

```
delete a from yourtable a 
join 
(select *, row_number() OVER (partition by ordernum, cost ORDER BY ordernum, cost desc) rownum from yourtable )b
on a.ordernum=b.ordernum
where rownum<>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to delete the smaller cost of each `OrderNum` like below :

```
DELETE Orders.*
FROM Orders
join (Select OrderNum, max(cost) as cost FROM Orders 
      GROUP BY [OrderNum] HAVING Count(*) > 1) as R
on Orders.OrderNum=R.OrderNum and Orders.cost < R.cost
```